# How to replace between certain word and a character

Tags: text-processing

I have a bunch of files in a directory and I'd like to replace between `width` and the first `>`.
Each file has a different `width` value.

One file has:

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="512px"
 height="512px"><path //removed for brevity
```

Another file has:

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="415px"
 height="450px"><path //removed for brevity
```

etc.

I'd like to replace them to the following:

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="{size}" 
height="{size}" viewBox="0 0 512 512" fill={color} 
class={$$props.class} {...$$restProps} aria-label={ariaLabel}><path 
//removed for brevity
```

I tried the following but it is not working:

```
sed -i 's/width.*>/width={size} height={size} viewBox="0 0 512 512" 
fill={color} 
class={$$props.class} {...$$restProps} aria-label={ariaLabel}/' ./*.*
```

Comment: **(1)** Will width, height & closing character occur on one line, not crossing to multiple lines ? **(2)** Will width occur (2A) only one time throughout the Document, or (2B) occur multiple multiple times but only one should be changed or (2C) occur multiple times & all should be changed ? **(3)** Only SED , not AWK, Perl or Python ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is probably that `sed` works linewise, while the `svg` format allows line breaks, which seems to be the case here. Thus, there is no line with `width`, followed by a `>` somewhere, so there is no replacement.

But it could be worse, because the `path` element could be on the same line, so it would get eaten completely by your `.*`!

I suggest to replace `width` and `height` separately:

```
sed 's/width="[^"]*/width="{size}/;s/height[^"]*"/height="{size}" viewBox="0 0 512 512" fill={color} class={$$props.class} {...$$restProps} aria-label={ariaLabel} /' ./*.*
```

- I removed the `-i` option, please don't re-add it before testing
- `[^"]*` matches all characters which are not `"`, so it keeps you from removing more than expected
- I removed the newlines in your code, because I don't know whether they were intentional. Actual newlines in the replacement would need to be preceeded by a backslash

Comment: This removed version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" from <svg width="420" height="512" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="m53.97...."/></svg>. Is there any way not to remove them?

Comment: Your example doesn't contain it in this order, but I modified my answer to cover this order as well. Please update your question to ask for what your really need.

Answer (score 1):

`-i` is an option that some (not all) `sed` implementations have borrowed from `perl`. `perl` makes it easier here:

```
perl -0777 -pi -e 's{\bwidth=".*?>}{width="{size}" 
height="{size}" viewBox="0 0 512 512" fill={color} 
class={\$\$props.class} {...\$\$restProps} aria-label={ariaLabel}>}gs' yourfile
```

Where:

- `-0777` processes the file as a whole instead of one line at a time
- `s{...}{...}` is another way to write `s/.../.../` but without having to worry about `/` characters in pattern or replacement. `{`, `}` inside are fine as long as they're matched.
- `*?` is the non-greedy version of `*`.
- `\b` is a word boundary, so it doesn't match the `width="` in `minwidth="` for instance. It would still match in `min-width="` though. If that's a problem, replace it with `(?<=\s)` (which stands for *as long as preceded by a whitespace*).
- The `s` flag is so that `.*` can span several lines if need be (for `.` to also match on newline characters). Remove the `g` flag to only replace the first occurrence.

To only do it in `<svg>` tags:

```
perl -0777 -pi -e 's{<svg[^<>]*\bwidth="\K.*?>}{{size}" 
height="{size}" viewBox="0 0 512 512" fill={color} 
class={\$\$props.class} {...\$\$restProps} aria-label={ariaLabel}>}gs' yourfile
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`.

```
$  sed -i.bak s'~\(width="\)[^>]*~\1{size}" height="{size}" viewBox="0 0 512 512" fill={color} class={$$props.class} {...$$restProps} aria-label={ariaLabel}~' input_file
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="{size}" height="{size}" viewBox="0 0 512 512" fill={color} class={$$props.class} {...$$restProps} aria-label={ariaLabel}><path //removed for brevity
```

Comment: Just code, no explanation, and even unlikely to address the problem.